# How would I implement a StackOverflow-like Markdown in PHP?

Tags: php, markdown

#### What am I looking for?

I am looking for a markdown language that works similiar to the one used here on stackoverflow.

#### Possible solutions

I could go and write my own Markup language but I think this will be a waste of time. This is a possibility though.

What I really want to know is if the StackOverflow markdown language is opensource or if there are similiar opensource packages available for use in PHP.

Comment: Something like  https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown or http://parsedown.org/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Markdown Implementation

You should look for an already existing library that you can plug in and use.

Firstly you need to decide between two major groups of markdown implementations

- basic
- extended (tables etc)

Stackexchange uses what I would call basic or original markdown.

Some search terms you should explore:

- Basic

  - John Gruber Markdown
  - CommonMark
  - PHP Markdown
- Extended

  - Fletcher Penney MultiMarkdown
  - PHP Markdown Extra
  - PHP MultiMarkdown
  - PHP Parsedown

I use PHP Parsedown. I find it effective but a bit quirky and intolerant.

You should note that the Markdown definition is very fractured, apart from CommonMark the markup used by the original and other implementations isn't well-defined and so different implementations will often produce different results and support different features.

### Security

There are some security concerns. Markdown accessible to end-users allows them to insert arbitrary HTML which can introduce cross-site scripting and other security problems. You may need to pre-process the markup or post-process the HTML to remove problematic elements. Stackexchange allows only a limited subset of HTML for this reason.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive and well-formed explanation.